# Python File Not Closing Properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

My file is not being closed properly and I cannot figure out why:

```
open_sample_file = codecs.open(ssis_txt_files_2[a], 'r', "utf-16")


whatever = open_sample_file.readlines()

open_sample_file.close
print(open_sample_file)
```

output:

```
<codecs.StreamReaderWriter object at 0x0331F3B0>
```

Shouldn't the output return `None`?

Comment: `open_sample_file.close` is a function, you have to call it: `open_sample_file.close()`

Comment: @RafaelC also a good way for op to have figured this out is how would accessing a variable called close *actually close* the file without any `__get_attribute__` magic.

Comment: Why are you using `codecs.open` in Python 3? Just use the built-in `open`, which takes an `encoding` arg in Python 3. And if you open your files using `with` they'll be closed automatically.

Comment: @pm 2Ring: The file I am working with is utf-16 and that's the only way I could open the file.

Comment: No, `with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-16") as open_sample_file:` will work fine. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: The linked question isn't an exact match, but the answers there have some good relevant info to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you need to call the close method:

```
open_sample_file.close()
```

Then, what will result is a closed file, not `None`.

```
>>> open_sample_file
<closed file 'filename', mode 'r' at 0x109a965d0>
```

Finally, the usual way to handle files in Python is using [with-statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), which take care of closing the file for you:

```
with codecs.open(filename) as open_sample_file:
    # do work
# the file will be closed automatically when the block is done
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I receive some sort of error message when I used open_sample_file.close? What happened in python since I didn't get an error message? I am just curious.

Comment: It's not an error: `open_sample_file.close` is just a way to referer to the method as something you can call without calling it. It can be useful to treat functions as data.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is just a way to referer to the method as something you can call without calling it."

Comment: If you have a function `f`, sometimes you don't want to call it directly, for example if you write `map(f, [1,2,3])` (and not `map(f(), [1,2,3])`).

Answer (score 2):

You have to call 
    `open_sample_file.close()`